# Editing Subversion post-commit script to enable automated Hudson builds

Tags: linux, svn, hudson, hook, post-commit

Hey guys, I'm not so good with Linux, but I need to modify the post-commit file of my Subversion repository to get Hudson to build automatically on commits.

This page [here](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Subversion+Plugin) tells me to do this:

```
REPOS="$1"
REV="$2"
UUID=`svnlook uuid $REPOS`
/usr/bin/wget \
  --header "Content-Type:text/plain;charset=UTF-8" \
  --post-data "`svnlook changed --revision $REV $REPOS`" \
  --output-document "-" \
  http://server/hudson/subversion/${UUID}/notifyCommit?rev=$REV
```

The part that I don't know is the address URL given at the bottom of that code snippet. I know the address of my Hudson server, but the `/subversion` part has me baffled, because on my system that doesn't refer to anything. My Subversion repository belongs somewhere else on the server, not inside Hudson. Can anyone tell me what I'm supposed to put as the URL (an example would help greatly)?

Comment: Why don't you let Hudson check Subversion if something has changed? Much more simpler...

Answer (score 1):

http://server/hudson/subversion is an addressed managed by your Hudson, not by your SVN Apache server (which can indeed be another server entirely)

You have nothing to change except put the name of your Hudson server.